# Swipe gesture mistaken for touch down

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrolevents

I have a `UIScrollView` with three sections that can be swiped to. On each section, there is a `UIButton`, and the user is supposed to select one of buttons. My problem is that if the user swipes through the `UIButton`, it is accidentally selected. My question is, what `UIControlEvent` should I set my `UIButtons` to so they don't mistake a swipe for a touch down?

here is the code for my button:

```
    var button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake((bigSizes.width * (50/960)), (bigSizes.height * 20/568), (bigSizes.width * 220/960), (bigSizes.height * 300/568)))
    button1.setImage(image1, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    view1.addSubview(button1)
    button1.addTarget(self, action: "button1Pressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass this button problem if you instead use a `UIImageView` with a tap gesture recognizer:

```
var button1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake((bigSizes.width * (50/960)), (bigSizes.height * 20/568), (bigSizes.width * 220/960), (bigSizes.height * 300/568)))
button1.image = image1
button1.userInteractionEnabled = true
view1.addSubview(button1)
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
button.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

With, obviously a `handleTap:` method:

```
func handleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // handle tap
}
```